# Outlook - How can I see a locally deleted email?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

After I delete a message in Outlook 2013, I don't see it in the Deleted Items folder.  Where is it located, and how can I undelete it?

**UPDATE:** If this is not supported easily: How can I move Outlook emails to a Recycle bin or the like?

**UPDATE 2:** I'm using IMAP.  My question is "How can I tell Outlook, when I 'delete' something, to just move it to a Trash Bin etc., so that it is still stored locally? And, when I do that, how can I pull that message back up, and *undelete* it"

Comment: You cannot configure Outlook to place emails into the `Recycle Bin`.  If emails are not moved to the deleted folder then you have a software configuration problem

Comment: @Ramhound I think they mean _a_ recycling bin, in a more general context, not THE Recycling Bin. ;)

Comment: @SRobertJames What type of email account is in question? Exchange, POP3, IMAP?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - I am not sure I agree.  They used the term `Recycle bin` which I naturally assumed mean the `recycle bin`